# Python matplotlib internal latex rendering has non-uniform legend label spacing?

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, latex, legend

Using the latex symbol for a right arrow (`\rightarrow`) for legend labels, with the internal latex rendering in `matplotlib`, adjusts the line spacing between label entries; see the minimal example below, it creates the two attached png figures. Is there a way to keep uniform label spacing, while using the latex symbol (the parameter `labelspacing` for `plt.legend()` does not seem to work for this)? I understand that the line spacing should be wider for tall symbols or fractions or so, but the arrow is actually smaller than the text characters.

Specifications: python 3.7.6, matplotlib 3.1.2

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)

def plot_example(plot_case):
    plt.plot(x, y, label=r'test case a1')
    plt.plot(x, y, label=r'test case b1')
    if plot_case == 'good':
        plt.plot(x, y, label=r'test case c1')
        plt.plot(x, y, label=r'test case d1')
        plt.plot(x, y, label=r'test case e1')
    elif plot_case == 'bad':
        plt.plot(x, y, label=r'test case c1 $\rightarrow$ c2')
        plt.plot(x, y, label=r'test case d1 $\rightarrow$ d2')
        plt.plot(x, y, label=r'test case e1 $\rightarrow$ e2')
    handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
    plt.legend(handles, labels, fontsize=7)
    plt.savefig('~/test_legend_labelspacing_latex_arrow_%s.png' % plot_case)
    plt.close()

plot_example('good')
plot_example('bad')
```

[image: good case]
[image: bad case]

Comment: Most probably this is the same issue as https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/15313

Comment: Could be, but as far as I could see when briefly checking the posts, the issue has not been fixed yet, right?

Comment: Correct. If it is the same issue it is still present.

Answer (score 0):

work around can be

```
plt.legend(handles, labels, fontsize=7, handleheight=2.5)
```